# Как сделать такой блок (RoadMap)?

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой блок? Если точнее, то именно первую часть задачи (линия с анимацией),не знаю как сделать изогнутые линии с помощью CSS (возможно ли такое вообще).

По линии необходимо сделать пробегание желтого круга, символизирующего монету и она должна падать в мешок. Ширина монеты не шире линии роадмапа.

При наведении на какой то этап фон становится синий и появляется как свечение при этом вылетает блок с текстом описания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: три часа ушло на это: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GbxoEY

Comment: Круто, но я сделал несколько иным способом))
[ссылка](http://webdevep.takercorporation.com/)

Comment: Нет, я задавал на тостере и здесь.

Comment: в мобильной версии roadmap ломается

Comment: пока не делал адаптацию